# C++/WinRT runtime component to return large array

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I am trying to write a windows runtime component using C++/WinRT that will be consumed from C# for unity programme. I am completely new C++, but having spent a long time, I have managed to make the code work by returning  `Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap` object that came through the windows API. But returning the `SoftwareBitmap` is slow and I changed my code to return `com_array` instead.

Returning the `com_array` does speed up things significantly, but now I am running into **Access violation reading location xxxxx** error frequently. As someone with limited experience in C++, I am struggling to do this properly. Below is the simplified version of my code. I've removed majority of code for simplicity.

### 1.FrameData

```
#FrameData.idl

runtimeclass FrameData
    {
        RMFrameData();
        BYTE[] imageArray;
    }

#FrameData.h
struct FrameData : FrameData <RMFrameData>
{
    RMFrameData() = default;
    ~RMFrameData();

    com_array<uint8_t>& imageArray();
    void imageArray(array_view<uint8_t const> value);

private:
    com_array<uint8_t> m_imageArray{};
};

#FrameData.cpp
 RMFrameData::~RMFrameData()
 {
     m_imageArray.clear();
 }
com_array<uint8_t>& RMFrameData::imageArray()
{
    return m_imageArray;
}
void RMFrameData::imageArray(array_view<uint8_t const> value)
{
    m_imageArray = winrt::com_array<BYTE>(std::move_iterator(value.begin()), std::move_iterator(value.end()));
}
```

### Method that uses FrameData to send it is below.

```
void PVProcessor::OnFrameArrived(const MediaFrameReader& sender, const MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs& args)
    {

        if (MediaFrameReference frame = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame())
        {
            auto frame_data = winrt::make_self<winrt::HL2CV_WRT::implementation::RMFrameData>();

            if (frame != nullptr && frame.VideoMediaFrame() != nullptr) {
    
                uint32_t pixelBufferDataLength = 0;
                uint8_t* pixelBufferData;
                SoftwareBitmap bitmap = SoftwareBitmap::Convert(frame.VideoMediaFrame().SoftwareBitmap(), BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8);
                if (bitmap != nullptr) {
                    BitmapBuffer bitmapBuffer = bitmap.LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode::Read);

                    auto spMemoryBufferByteAccess{ bitmapBuffer.CreateReference().as<::Windows::Foundation::IMemoryBufferByteAccess>() };
                    winrt::check_hresult(spMemoryBufferByteAccess->GetBuffer(&pixelBufferData, &pixelBufferDataLength));

                    std::vector<BYTE> pixelVectorData{};
                    pixelVectorData.insert(pixelVectorData.end(), std::make_move_iterator(pixelBufferData), std::make_move_iterator(pixelBufferData + pixelBufferDataLength));
                    frame_data->imageArray(pixelVectorData); //set com_array here.
                    bitmap.Close();
                }

            }
            frame.Close();
            m_frame_data_available(*this, *frame_data);
        }
    }
```

### Method using the FrameData from C# is below.

```
void OneFrameAvailable(object sender, RMFrameData e){
  
        var array = e.imageArray;
        
 /*
    use array data here
 */
    }
```

the code `var array = e.imageArray;` is throwing error **Access violation reading location xxxx**.

My questions are

1. how do I properly initialize `m_imageArray` in **FrameData.h**.
2. Is the destructor correctly cleaning up `m_imageArray` after using it in C#?
3. Do I need to explicitly call destructor from C# code after using frame data?
4. I wrote the C++ code thinking like java, so I am sure there are many many mistakes. Please let me know other things that need to be corrected.
5. The goal is to be able to access `softwarebitmap`'s data from `c#` without needing to make copies along the way. How?
   Thanks.

Comment: *"But returning the `SoftwareBitmap` is slow"* - how did you determine that this were slow? This is returning a pointer plus a reference count. No copying is involved. You seem to be trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @IInspectable I just add in timers to see how long everything is taking. In Unity C#, I have to turn SoftwareBitmap to byte[] using softwarebitmap.CopyToBuffer(bytes.AsBuffer()); so that I can apply it as a texture in Unity. This step is also taking 500+ms. Also, from other API that doesn't return SoftwareBitmap, but return frame->GetBuffer(&pImage, &outBufferCount);, I have to return &pImage as byte[]. Therefore, I am trying to return byte[] from C++/WinRT.

Comment: Could you tell me if you use the MediaCapture object to capture the camera data in the C++/WinRT component?

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT Yes. I use MediaCapture object to capture camera data in C++/WinRT for PVCamera (PhotoVideo Camera). At the same time, I use the newly release HL2 Research mode apis to get other sensor streams.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error based on the code provided by you. Could you provide us a sample for testing by using OneDerive or GitHub?